# Using source() fucntion in r/Rstudio to read the first 100 rows of R file

Tags: r

Simple question: I need to read only the first `100` rows of my soruce R file: `File.R`.

How can I do this?

`source(here::here('R/Code_Files/File.R'))`

Comment: Try `source(textConnection(readLines(here::here('R/Code_Files/File.R'), n = 100)))`.

Comment: I have this error message `Error in textConnection(readLines(here::here("R/Code_Files/File.R"),  : 
  argument 'object' must deparse to a single character string`

Comment: Try doing it in two steps: `tmp <- readLines(here::here('R/Code_Files/File.R'), n = 100); source(textConnection(tmp))`.  If that doesn't work, edit your question with some more detail of the full code tried and a sample of the contents of `File.R`.